# Java method to just put a file in a folder (both as parameters)

Tags: java

I been searching this forum and many other resources to try and get an answer to my Java conundrum but to no avail and I can't use Apache commons.

I've hit a brick wall with trying to put a file into a specific folder; the folder is already created using .mkdir() :

```
public void createRepositoryDir(String pRepositoryName)
    {
        File repositoryDir = new File(pRepositoryName);
        repositoryDir.mkdir();
    }
```

The file is chosen using JFileChooser and returned as a File object but I’m finding it difficult to put that file into the directory (`repositoryDir.mkdir();`).

I need to pass the directory location and file location as parameters as I am using a menu based system.

I have already tried:

```
File file = new File(dir, pFile);
```

But again it seems to be a clash between File and String types.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean by *clash between File and String types*? Do you get any compile error(s)?

Comment: To clarify, is it safe to assume you are: choosing an existing file using JFileChooser and want to then move that file from its existing location into a new directory?

Comment: File objects don't represent the content of the file, they only represent the name and location of the file. You cannot move a physical file by only manipulating File objects. You will need to copy the contents of the source file to the destination file (and then optionally delete the source file).

Comment: renameTo is just ok to move files. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/File.html#renameTo%28java.io.File%29 Does that help?

Comment: A4L: the method needed either ‘String, String’ or ‘File, String’ as a parameter format.
Jason: Yes, that is where I keep going wrong; I need to get out of the mind-set of presuming that the object will automatically provide its fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `pFile` is your source file and `dir` is your target directory, you will need to create a new target file:

```
File targetFile = new File(dir, pFile.getName());
```

Then, you need to copy the contents of pFile to targetFile. You can do this many different ways, however here is one (exception handling has been omitted for clarity):

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(pFile);
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(targetFile);
copyStream(fis, fos, 10000);
fos.flush();
fos.close();
fis.close();
```

Where the copyStream method is defined as:

```
public static void copyStream(final InputStream inputStream, final OutputStream outputStream, final int bufferLength) throws IOException {
    // copy the input stream to the output stream
    byte[] buf = new byte[bufferLength];
    int len;
    while ((len = inputStream.read(buf)) > 0) {
        outputStream.write(buf, 0, len);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jason that code described it precisely, thank you, much appreciated!

Comment: Don't forget to close your inputstream and flush and close your outputstream afterwards. See edited above.

Comment: Thanks Jason will do that.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a new file only won't work.

If you can use Java 1.7, you are in safe hands: check out the [Files](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html) class.

However it uses new java.nio.Path instead of java.io.File, so you have to create a Path-object:

```
FileSystem fs = FileSystems.getDefault();
Path p = fs.getPath( "C:/Windows/" );
```